# Random group with fixed match

Tags: javascript

I'm making a random group for an one-on-one debate, there are 16 people divided into 8 teams, and they will be assigned with 8 random topics as well as random sides(AFF & NEG).
Below is the part I used to generate random teams, the match will be held on am and pm so 8 per round.
For some reason we need two of them to be always in a match. I can't seem to do this in a logical way. I.E. Jerry Lin always debates with Sammy Singh, sides can change. Thanks in advance.

```js
var team = [
"Sandra Tom*",
  "Jerry Lin*",
  "Josh Renaud*",
  "Katie Bostian",
  "Sammy Singh",
  "Nader Shehayed*",
  "Joseph Tu*",
  "James Kim"
];
var text = "";

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    var temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}


function shuffler() {
  shuffle(team);
  document.getElementById("player-0").innerHTML = team[0];
  document.getElementById("player-1").innerHTML = team[1];
  document.getElementById("player-2").innerHTML = team[2];
  document.getElementById("player-3").innerHTML = team[3];
  document.getElementById("player-4").innerHTML = team[4];
  document.getElementById("player-5").innerHTML = team[5];
  document.getElementById("player-6").innerHTML = team[6];
  document.getElementById("player-7").innerHTML = team[7];
}

// var myInterval = setInterval(shuffler, 50);
// clearInterval(myInterval);

document.getElementById("random").addEventListener("click", shuffler);

window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, false);
 
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.charCode == "32") {
      document.getElementById("random").addEventListener("click", shuffler);    
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}

#team {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}

#team td {
  height: 75px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, san-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#team .title {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#team .blue {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#team .red {
  background-color: tomato;
}

#team .green {
  background-color: olive;
}

#team .orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

#team .grey {
  background-color: #686868;
}

.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
   }
```

```html
  <table align="center" id="team" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="title">
        Team 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="player-0" class="blue"></td>
      <td id="player-1" class="blue"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="title">
        Team 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="player-2" class="red"></td>
      <td id="player-3" class="red"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="title">
        Team 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="player-4" class="green"></td>
      <td id="player-5" class="green"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="title">
        Team 4
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="player-6" class="orange"></td>
      <td id="player-7" class="orange"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="600" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <button id="random">RANDOM</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Update:Snippet attached.
To clarify the question.
We want Jerry Lin always debates with Sammy Singh. 8 topics divided into am and pm, 16 people divided into 8 groups for those 8, all unique.

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: I don't really get the question

Comment: @0stone0 I want two specific person to be always in the same game.

Comment: @DSteman I want two specific person to be always in the same game. Jerry Lin always debates with Sammy Singh, no matter what the subject they are in.

Comment: Ahh, please [edit] your question to clarify that. Also, could you please add a [mre] the the question? No need for a JSFIddle, should be fine with a StackSnippet.

Comment: Adjust teams array so there are 4 items with 2 teams per item

Comment: @0stone0 Snippet attached. Question edited. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @DSteman in that case we are having all 4 teams with fixed combination, but we only want two people to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the two people who are always on the same team, then hack the shuffled team list. Check my solution below:

```js
var team = [
"Sandra Tom*",
  "Jerry Lin*",
  "Josh Renaud*",
  "Katie Bostian",
  "Sammy Singh",
  "Nader Shehayed*",
  "Joseph Tu*",
  "James Kim"
];
var text = "";

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    var temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

function hack(array, p1, p2){
  var p1Index = array.indexOf(p1);
  var p2Index = array.indexOf(p2);

  if(p1Index % 2 === 0){
    var temp = array[p1Index+1]
    array[p1Index+1] = array[p2Index]
  } else {
    var temp = array[p1Index-1]
    array[p1Index-1] = array[p2Index]
  }

  array[p2Index] = temp
  return array
}

function shuffler() {
  var shuffled = shuffle(team)
  var hacked = hack(shuffled, "Jerry Lin*", "Sammy Singh")
  var final = hacked

  document.getElementById("player-0").innerHTML = final[0];
  document.getElementById("player-1").innerHTML = final[1];
  document.getElementById("player-2").innerHTML = final[2];
  document.getElementById("player-3").innerHTML = final[3];
  document.getElementById("player-4").innerHTML = final[4];
  document.getElementById("player-5").innerHTML = final[5];
  document.getElementById("player-6").innerHTML = final[6];
  document.getElementById("player-7").innerHTML = final[7];
}

// var myInterval = setInterval(shuffler, 50);
// clearInterval(myInterval);

document.getElementById("random").addEventListener("click", shuffler);

window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, false);
 
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.charCode == "32") {
      document.getElementById("random").addEventListener("click", shuffler);
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}

#team {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}

#team td {
  height: 75px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, san-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#team .title {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#team .blue {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#team .red {
  background-color: tomato;
}

#team .green {
  background-color: olive;
}

#team .orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

#team .grey {
  background-color: #686868;
}

.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Random Team Generator</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"> -->
  
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<body>
  <table align="center" id="team" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="title">
        Team 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="player-0" class="blue"></td>
      <td id="player-1" class="blue"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="title">
        Team 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="player-2" class="red"></td>
      <td id="player-3" class="red"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="title">
        Team 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="player-4" class="green"></td>
      <td id="player-5" class="green"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="title">
        Team 4
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="player-6" class="orange"></td>
      <td id="player-7" class="orange"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="600" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <button id="random">RANDOM</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<!-- partial -->
  <!-- <script  src="./script.js"></script> -->
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are a star man! Work like a charm. I knew there should be a neater way. I was going to separate the array into two group. Group-1 with 6 random and Group-2 with 2 fixed match and then shuffle them into w 2-dims array and then shuffle again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments:

```
var team = [
  ["Sandra Tom*","Jerry Lin*"],
  ["Josh Renaud*","Katie Bostian"],
  ["Sammy Singh","Nader Shehayed*"],
  ["Joseph Tu*","James Kim"]
];
var text = "";

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    var temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}


function shuffler() {
  shuffle(team);
  document.getElementById("player-0").innerHTML = team[0][0];
  document.getElementById("player-1").innerHTML = team[0][1];
  document.getElementById("player-2").innerHTML = team[1][0];
  document.getElementById("player-3").innerHTML = team[1][1];
  document.getElementById("player-4").innerHTML = team[2][0];
  document.getElementById("player-5").innerHTML = team[2][1];
  document.getElementById("player-6").innerHTML = team[3][0];
  document.getElementById("player-7").innerHTML = team[3][1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but not working.

Comment: What do you miss in this solution?

Comment: Tried your script and it even won't return any result.

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/eo29dxyr/1/ it's returning a selection there

Comment: Okay, tried your fiddle, like I said, we only want Jerry Lin always debates with Sammy Singh, the rest are still random.